# Accessing two databases in a single mysql query using PDO Connection

Tags: php, pdo

How do I access common information between two tables with different structure in different databases in a single query .

I used the follwing code but it is not working:

```
$pd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname1", 'username', 'paasword');    
$stmt = $pd->prepare("select a.siteid
            FROM dbname1.users a,dbname2.user b 
            WHERE a.firstname = b.firstname AND a.lastname=b.lastname"); 
$stmt ->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($rows);
$this->data = $rows;
```

It gives me an output of Array[0]. Please help me out with this.

Comment: You might want to fetch the information from the two tables into 2 separate arrays and then compare those arrays. You would need at least 2 connection objects and 2 queries for that.

Comment: The way you're doing it should work fine. Does the query work if you run it by hand?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Why would he need two connection objects? The database in the connection object is just used as the default, you can always specify another database explicitly, using the syntax he wrote.

Comment: Try enabling PDO exception mode, in case you're getting errors: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Does it really give you NO output? Or does it dump `Array(0)`?

Comment: @Barmar can you simultaneously connect to two different databases on same PDO object ?

Comment: Hello @Barmar, it shows Array (0). But there are many common tuples between those two tables. I have checked the query manually and it works fine and shows common tuples too. I have tried a simple query to view the table contents from the second database by calling it explicitly but it still gives me Array(0).

Comment: @Maximus2012, I have tried giving two connections but I cannot understand how to compare those two arrays and send it into a single array.

Comment: @SirishaGavini in that case you need to update your question with this additional information.

Comment: As long as the two databases are on the same server, you can use one connection. The database you name in the connection object is just the default. You can specify other databases as I did in the answer.

Comment: If running the query manually works, and you used the same username as in the script, then I can't think of a reason why it would return a different result.

Comment: @Maximus2012  I have followed your suggestion and fetched the table information in two arrays and compared it and it worked. Thank you so much :-)